# Check for new files in a loop - java

Tags: java, loops

I have a program that needs to read files. I need to check every 10 seconds if there is new files.

To do that, I've made this :

```
ArrayList<File>oldFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
ArrayList<File>files=new ArrayList<File>();
while(isFinished != true){
        files=listFilesForFolder(folder);
        if(oldFiles.size() != files.size()){
            System.out.println("Here is when a new file(s) is(are) in the folder");
        }
        Thread.sleep(10000);
}
```

Basically, the listFilesForFolder is getting a folder destination, and check the files in there.

**My problem** : My program does every loop my reading function on every file. I want to do my reading function *ONLY* on new files.

How can I do something like :

> new files -  old files = my files I want to read.

Comment: Not the answer but note that the check is incorrect. If a file has been deleted and a new file has been created within 10 sec you will not detect the new file as you are checking for the lists size rather than content

Comment: Could you move the processed files into a separate folder? Than the actual folder would either be empty (nothing to do) or contain new files.

Comment: Off topic, but check out this idiom for thread sleep: `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10)` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html

Comment: @giorashc : Yep that comparison was poor !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than comparing old and new files, why not write a method to just return Last Modified Files.

```
public static ArrayList<File> listLastModifiedFiles(File folder,
        long sleepDuration) throws Exception {

    ArrayList<File> newFileList = new ArrayList<File>();

    for (File fileEntry : folder.listFiles())
        if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - fileEntry.lastModified()) <= sleepDuration)
            newFileList.add(fileEntry);

    return newFileList;
}
```

//Sample usage:

```
long sleepDuration = 10000;
ArrayList<File> newFileList;
int counter = 10;

while (counter-- > 0) {
    newFileList = listLastModifiedFiles(folder, sleepDuration);

    for (File File : newFileList)
        System.out.println(File.getName());

    Thread.sleep(sleepDuration);
}
```

Comment: Ok guys, I need help one more time. I want to stop my loop in other class. I've tried setting boolean isOver instead of counter-- >10. And acessing it with setter but that doesn't work . :/

Comment: It would be helpful if you raise a new question, with relevant source code. It will give more insight.

Comment: I'll do that ! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Rather than your approach why not store the DateTime of the last time that you checked.

Then compare this time to the [File.lastModified](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified()) value

The problem with your appraoch is that the array sizes will be different even in a file is deleted, and will be the same if one file is deleted and one file is added.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html). Instead of returning an `ArrayList`, you could return a set instead.

```
newFiles.removeAll(oldFiles);
```

would then give you all the files that are not in the old set. I'm not saying that working with the modification date as Scary Wombat has pointed out is a worse idea, I'm just offering another solution.

Additionally, you have to modify your `oldFiles` to hold all files you've already encountered. The following example I think does what you're trying to achieve.

```
private static Set<File> findFilesIn(File directory) {
    // Or whatever logic you have for finding files
    return new HashSet<File>(Arrays.asList(directory.listFiles()));
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    Set<File> allFiles = new HashSet<File>(); // Renamed from oldFiles
    Set<File> newFiles = new HashSet<File>();

    File dir = new File("/tmp/stackoverflow/");
    while (true) {
        allFiles.addAll(newFiles); // Add files from last round to collection of all files

        newFiles = findFilesIn(dir);
        newFiles.removeAll(allFiles); // Remove all the ones we already know.

        System.out.println(String.format("Found %d new files: %s", newFiles.size(), newFiles));
        System.out.println("Sleeping...");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Sets are a more appropiate data storage for your case since you don't need any order in your collection of files and can benefit from faster lookup times (when using a `HashSet`).

Comment: ArrayList already implements that method, see the link in my answer

Comment: Yes, I've read your answer and thought about it but the lookup time in an ArrayList will be worst case O(n) while a `HashSet` has O(1). If OP has to deal with many files this may become important.

Comment: Yes, I've to deal with many "little" files (eg.5Mb)
Thanks for all the answer ! I'm working on it !

Comment: Apparently, this thing does not work properly : in my loop : it works the first iteration but after it doesn't, and then it 're-works' and after not.... :/

Comment: Let me add a quick example on how I meant my answer.

Comment: @tmylamoule Have a look at the answer now. I've tried coding it up myself and ran into an issue but I have a working example for you now (don't forget to upvote :P)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you only need to detect new files, not modified ones, and no file will be removed while your code is running:
ArrayList implements [`removeAll(Collection c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)), which does exactly what you want:

> Removes from this list all of its elements that are contained in the
>   specified collection.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using the Java WatchService API which uses the low level operating system to notify you of changes to the file system. It's more efficient and faster than listing the files in directory.

There is a tutorial at [Watching a Directory for Changes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) and the API is documented here: [Interface WatchService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html)